# Stopping a daemon thread on the AS400 using QShell

Tags: java, daemon, ibm-midrange

I have a java program which I start with the comman `java -jar MyProgram.jar`, and I can stop the java program using the command `java -jar MyProgram.jar stop`. I am having trouble running my command in the same shell because the previous program is running, is there another way to open another QShell or a way to run another command in the same shell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Qsh does not support job control, and you can only open one for each session.

The easiest is to open yet another green screen session and run a second qsh inthere

Note that typing SysReq-2 stops the current program, too.

Comment: You May also consider looking into running with SBMJOB and RUNJVA.  This will put in batch which give the background job you are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

A daemon is presumably intended to be a long-running background service.  As such, you would normally be submitting this to run in a some batch subsystem. You would normally use ENDJOB on it from another session.

See your system administrator for details on where they want your job to run on this particular system.  There are various options,  and testing may be different than how they wish it to run in production.